# google wallet for digital goods - let user determine price

Tags: android-pay

I've got google wallet for digital goods working fine for fixed price items. However, I would like to sell user priced items or subscriptions (i.e., pay what you want or can). So the user would enter the price they want to pay.

However, I cannot seem to find any way to do this with google wallet for digital goods. Any ideas or tips?

Answer (score 0):

The key item is for the `JWT` to be generated server-side.

A trivial example is [here](http://code.edchavez.com/iap-dotnet)

- Pls. note that I just mocked this so I'm not doing a lot of validations to user input - so please be gentle - it's just for reference showing how you can accomplish things.
- Also this says *nothing* of Google's policy (check with them about donations)....

In summary what the sample does:

1. Allow user to provide some value in a standard `<input />`
2. Send data to server via Ajax (e.g. jQuery `$.post`) and generate the necessary `JWT` based on user input/s
3. If `JWT` is generated successfully, call `buy` (`google.payments.inapp.buy`) and supply it the server generated value (the `JWT`) returned from #2

E.g.

```js
$(function () {
        $("#donateForm").on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $("#donateForm").serialize();
            $.post("ajaxhandler.ashx", data)     //send to server to generate JWT 
            .done(function (d) {                 //d is the JWT in this sample

                google.payments.inapp.buy({
                    "parameters": {},
                    "jwt": d,                   //d goes here
                    "success": function (result) {
                        //handle Wallet success as you deem fit
                    },
                    "failure": function (result) {
                        //handle Wallet failures as you deem fit
                    }
                }
            );

            }).fail(function (f) {
                //handle ajax failure as you deem fit
            }).always(function (a) {
                //handle as you deem fit
            });

         ........
```

Hth...